# Trouble displaying images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to replicate the project explained in Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition.

While going through the book's exercises, step by step,  I am not able to see the images in my website.

In `products/index.html.erb`:

```
<td><%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %></td>
```

In `products/show.html.erb`:

```
<p><b>Image url:</b> <%= @product.image_url %></p>
```

And in `_form.html.erb`:

```
<div class="field"><%= f.label :image_url %><br /> <%= f.text_field :image_url %></div>
```

When i check the html source code it shows the path of `ruby.jpg` as

```
<img alt="Ruby" class="list_image" src="/images/ruby.jpg" />
```

That file lives in `depot/app/assets/images/ruby.jpg`

It is showing only the path, not the image. I restarted the server and cleared the cache but still the image is not displaying.

Comment: Please, share some code. How do you embed images in your templates?

Comment: in my products/index.html.erb file   <td>
            <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %>
          </td>

Comment: in products/show.html.erb file <p>
  <b>Image url:</b>
  <%= @product.image_url %>
</p>

Comment: So, what is `product.image_url` output and what do you see in compiled html?

Comment: And in _form.html.erb file   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>

Comment: in compiled html I see the alt tag values..

Comment: when i check the html source code it show the path of image as  <img alt="Ruby" class="list_image" src="/images/ruby.jpg" />  and I have saved my images in depot/app/assets/images/ruby.jpg

Comment: Try to use `image_path(product.image_url)` helper.

Comment: its showing the path of image and the alt tag  /assets/images/wd4d.jpg Wd4d

Comment: Its showing only the path not the image ... I restarted the server cleared the cache but still image is not displaying .

Comment: I'm not understand task you want to solve. Are you uploading image, or linking it by URL or just want to show up image from your assets?

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have noted, you need to give much more information up front. Ideally for a problem like this you should quote all bits of your app which try to show the image, so tell us what is in the model field (image_url), what is in the view, what is in the rendered html.

Start with one particular product and its image. First find out the image path, then check on disk if this image exists, then ask yourself why it is not being displayed, then perhaps try putting in a manual image link to test.

Try editing your question to fill in the blanks here:

Are you trying this locally or on a server (details of your setup are best)?

...

What do you see when you put this in your view

```
<%= product.image_url %>?
```

...

Where is the image file on disk relative to public (i.e. what is the path), can you find it?

...

Try a manual image tag to the path for the image on disk, what do you see? (e.g. for     public/system/images/4/4.jpg use

```
<%= image_tag('/system/images/4/4.jpg') %>)
```

...

If all else fails try placing an image manually in say public/test.jpg, and linking to it:

```
<%= image_tag('/public/test.jpg') %>
```

...